# Start/Stop node at runtime?

Tags: ros, c++, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is there a nice ROS-way to start a node at runtime (using C++) and after some time stop it again (without using system() etc.)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28867/start/stop-node-at-runtime?/) by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 345 on 2012-03-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At least for killing there is an xmlrpc shutdown call, which is what `rosnode kill` uses. That is probably the ROS'iest way to do it. Sending SIGINT would also be OK as ROS installs a SIGINT handler.

[Slave API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Slave_API)

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think so.

The ROS-way is for all nodes to run continuously until shutdown. If a node crashes, `roslaunch` can respawn it for you.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1